# Is there a way to change the Window 10 virtual desktop name

Tags: windows-10, virtual-desktop

In Windows 10 there are virtual desktops. Unfortunately, the are by default `Desktop 1`, `Desktop 2`, etc. Or as in my screenshot `Bureaublad 1`, `Bureaublad 2`. Is there a way to rename them to something more useful?

[image]